# Move mouse cursor with delays constantly and click when analog value above 300. Arduino Pro Micro

Tags: arduino, mouse

I am using Pro Micro as a USB Host and moving the cursor to predefined positions on the screen with a delay of 5 seconds. I'm using the AbsMouse library for absolute mouse cursor positions. What I want is, when the analog input goes above 300, I want it to perform XYZ function. Because I'm using delays of 5000, I can't poll the analog input always.

Basically, I want the cursor to move to these absolute positions continuously in a loop. Whenever the analog value goes above 300, it should perform the press and release functions. 
I am not able to understand how to use Elapsed `millis()` or interrupts. Please show exactly how can it be done in code.
Help Much appreciated.

```
#include <AbsMouse.h>
int sensorValue = 0;
void setup()
{
    AbsMouse.init(1920, 1080);
}

void loop()
{

    sensorValue = analogRead(A0);
    AbsMouse.move(640, 127);
    delay(5000);
    AbsMouse.move(640, 400);
    delay(5000);
    AbsMouse.move(640, 625);
    delay(5000);
    AbsMouse.move(1280, 127);
    delay(5000);
    AbsMouse.move(1280, 400);
    delay(5000);
    AbsMouse.move(1280, 625);
    delay(5000);

    if (sensorValue >= 300)
    {
        AbsMouse.press(MOUSE_LEFT);
        AbsMouse.release(MOUSE_LEFT);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implementing a delay of 5 seconds measuring elapsed milliseconds and reading the analog value while waiting goes like this:

```
startTime = millis();
while(millis()-startTime < 5000) {
    sensorValue = analogRead(A0);
    if (sensorValue >= 300) {
        AbsMouse.press(MOUSE_LEFT);
        AbsMouse.release(MOUSE_LEFT);
    }
}
```

This has two disadvantages that you'll have to solve if needed. The first one is that the click events will be performed while the value stays above 300 (i.e. it can click more than once). The second problem, is that this is not an exact delay of 5 seconds, as it can have a jitter due to the code being executed inside the `while` block.

Another option, as you mentioned, is to use timer interrupts to achieve a more exact delay. Using a library like [TimerOne](https://github.com/PaulStoffregen/TimerOne/) it goes like this (inspired from library examples and modified to execute every 5 seconds):

```
#include <TimerOne.h>

void setup(void) {
  Timer1.initialize(5000000);
  Timer1.attachInterrupt(fiveSeconds);
}

void fiveSeconds(void) {
    // do stuff
}
```

The function `fiveSeconds` should be executed every 5 seconds, with more precision than the `millis()` approach.

Now you should add code to that function, to achieve what you want to do. I'd suggest to use `loop()` for reading the analog value and clicking, and the interrupt for moving the mouse cursor, but your approach might be different.

Comment: You just solved me this problem. Works perfectly. Thank you so so much!